# AIDE CMODs(специальная версия AIDE для lgl mod menu) не создает библиотеку c++

Tags: apk, aide, so

Работаю через эмулятор MEMU, до этого перепробовал популярные эмуляторы - исход тот же. В чем проблема? Мои друзья при создании apk через AIDE делают это успешно и изменения из Main.cpp в каталоге \app\src\main\jni\ изменения у них применяются. Логика данного мод меню такова, что изначально компилируется JNI в .so библиотеку, после в мод меню вызывается .so библиотека для дальнейшей работы уже в самом мод меню. Обобщим: моя проблема заключается в том, что у меня не компилируется та самая библиотека, зачастую приложение даже не стартует. Этой проблемы нет у моих друзей, владеющими физическими телефонами.

Исходники - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AcFW72hZDvUXhKv-ymQsVJpkUoB4RYwf/view

Официальная инструкция (после компиляции вылетает приложение, причина в отсутствии библиотеки) - https://github.com/LGLTeam/Android-Mod-Menu/wiki/Installation-(Android)

Answer (score 0):

Особенность AIDE при работе с разными устройствами - не полная поддержка разных архитектур и некоторых версий андроид. Как следствие - не компилируется библиотека .so. Как это исправить - ручками подбирать NDK и пробовать совмещать его с вашим устройством. Как считаю - шанс на работоспособность этого способа маловероятен. Однако, думаю, возможен и данный совет хоть чуть, но будет уместен.

Comment: ¿Выяснить, почему не компилируется библиотека - не вариант?

Comment: с телефона, во всяком случае, с моим опытом, это будет, скорее, невозможно.